# hide a checkbox in function another and disabled all elements to the checkbox disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function CheckBox(checkerbox, div) {
  if (checkerbox.checked) {
    document.getElementById(div, Urbanoo).style.display = "block"
  } else {
    document.getElementById(div, Rurall).style.display = "none"
    $("#Rurall").find("*").prop("disabled", true);
  }
}

function CheckBox1(checkerbox1, div) {
  if (checkerbox1.checked) {
    document.getElementById(div, Rurall).style.display = "block"
  } else {
    document.getElementById(div, Urbanoo).style.display = "none"
    $("#Urbanoo").find("*").prop("disabled", true);
  }
}
</script>
```

How to hide a checkbox in function another and disabled all elements to the checkbox disabled?

```
<input name="Rural" type="checkbox" onclick="CheckBox1(this,'Rurall');" />
<input name="Urbano" type="checkbox" onclick="CheckBox(this,'Urbanoo');" />  Urbanoo </center>

<div id="Urbanoo" style="display:none" >
    <g:render template="../DomUrbano/form"/>
</div>
```

The problem is that when I turn on a check box not the other box is not disabled

```
<div id="Rurall" style="display:none">
    </br>
    <g:render template="../DomRural/form"/>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the question / problem? Please show how  these functions are used and provide  relevant html. Also include explanation of expected behaviors

Comment: `</br>`? `getElementById(div,Urbanoo)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I see what you are attempting but frankly it's less than super clear.

SO what I think you want is;

1. Hide other checkboxes if I check one
2. If I do uncheck a box, show the other one again
3. Show a "partner" area if I check a box
4. Disable other NOT partner area inputs if I check a box

I modified your markup some to make it easier and also added some additional to clearly show what is happening.  I also added a data element for the partner to the input so we can make this all simpler and only have one function; now called via an event handler and NOT with inline code in markup.

Revised markup:

```
<span class="myinputs"><input class="mycheck" name="Rural" type="checkbox" data-partner="#Rurall" /> Rurall</span>
<span class="myinputs"><input class="mycheck" name="Urbano" type="checkbox" data-partner="#Urbanoo" /> Urbanoo</span>

<div id="Urbanoo" class="hidden others">the Urbannoo
  <g:render template="../DomUrbano/form" />
  <input type="textbox"/>
</div>
<div id="Rurall" class="hidden others">the Rurall
  <g:render template="../DomRural/form" />
  <input type="textbox"/>
</div>
```

Code:

```
$('.mycheck').on('change', function() {
  var amIChecked = $(this)[0].checked;
  $(this).parent().siblings('.myinputs').toggle(!amIChecked);
  var pt = $(this).data('partner');// get the partner selector
  $(pt).toggle(amIChecked);// show the partner in the others list
  //do the enable in the partner
  $('.others').filter(pt).toggle(amIChecked).find("*").prop("disabled", !amIChecked);
  //do the disable in the othes list not the partner
  $('.others').not(pt).find("*").prop("disabled", amIChecked);
});
```

Play with it all here: https://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/cLyb103x/1/

Comment: Thank you exactly what I needed.

Comment: Please , I could show the procedure to make a modal window

Comment: A new question perhaps?  Include what code you have tried

Comment: Thank you. This is my code just want to hide this button in div. Example : press the button hides the div . Pressing the button displays the div.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35162606/hide-various-buttons-with-different-div-javascript-within-a-form