# hide various buttons with different div Javascript within a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, grails, gsp

***this is my code***

press to hide , then press to display

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var clic = 1;
    function hideFecha(){
        if (clic == 1){
            document.getElementById('fecha').style.display='none';
            clic = clic + 1;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('fecha').style.display = 'block';      
            clic = 1;
        }   
    }
</script>
```

//press to hide , then press to display

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var click = 1;
    function hidePerson(){
        if (click == 1){
            document.getElementById('person').style.display='none';
            click = click + 1;}
        else{
            document.getElementById('person').style.display = 'block';      
            click = 1;
        }   
    }
</script>
```

***my form***

```
<g:form  controller="SoliCon" action="save" >
    <fieldset id="solContri" class="form">
        <div>
            <fieldset id="solContri" class="buttons">
                <center><input type="button" name="fecha" value="FECHA" onclick="hideFecha()"/></center>
            </fieldset>  
            <div id="fecha" >     
                <g:render  template="formfecha"/>
                <br>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Stylish button hides the div

```
        <div>
            <fieldset id="solContri" class="buttons">
                <input type="button" name="person"     value="PERSON"             onclick="hidePerson()"/>
            </fieldset>
            <div id="person">
                <g:render template="persona"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
</g:form>
```

Press to hide  then press to display The catch is that when there are two or more templates javascript code does not work.

ERROR  `hidePerson is not defined` , ERROR: `hideFecha is not defined`

Comment: I think your logic to hide is too complex. Why not just add a class called "hidden" and then use jQuery to add/remove that class when needed? Then in CSS the class hidden would use display:none.

Comment: I'm trying to do is hide and show the div with a button.Example : press the button hides the div . Pressing the button displays the div. The catch is that when there are two or more templates.  javascript code does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple issues with your code.

1.) You have multiple elements with the same id ( solContri )

2.) You have an extra closing div tag

The errors you were receiving were due to the duplicate ID.

See the code below. I believe it is what you are after.

```js
$("#solContri-person").click(function(){
 $("#person").hide();
});

$("#solContri-fecha").click(function(){
 $("#fecha").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset id="solContri" class="form">
  <div>
    <fieldset id="solContri-fecha" class="buttons">
      <center><input type="button" name="fecha" value="FECHA" /></center>
    </fieldset>  
    <div id="fecha" >     
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <fieldset id="solContri-person" class="buttons">
      <input type="button" name="person"     value="PERSON" />
    </fieldset>
    <div id="person">
<br/>
    </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```